# How to change kernel.perf_event_paranoid settings?

Tags: software-installation, kernel, 22.04, system-settings, tools

When trying to use the `perf` command, I get the following error message:

```
Access to performance monitoring and observability operations is limited.
Consider adjusting /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid setting to open
access to performance monitoring and observability operations for processes
without CAP_PERFMON, CAP_SYS_PTRACE or CAP_SYS_ADMIN Linux capability.
More information can be found at 'Perf events and tool security' document:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html
perf_event_paranoid setting is 4:
  -1: Allow use of (almost) all events by all users
      Ignore mlock limit after perf_event_mlock_kb without CAP_IPC_LOCK
>= 0: Disallow raw and ftrace function tracepoint access
>= 1: Disallow CPU event access
>= 2: Disallow kernel profiling
To make the adjusted perf_event_paranoid setting permanent preserve it
in /etc/sysctl.conf (e.g. kernel.perf_event_paranoid = <setting>)
```

But I am unable to change the file. I tried [this advice](https://superuser.com/questions/1404099/unable-to-change-kernel-perf-event-paranoid), but it does not work. Are there any other ways to change it?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings can be changed using the [`sysctl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) command, even without rebooting:

```
sudo sysctl kernel.perf_event_paranoid=<parameter>
```

<**parameter**> can be resumed as

```
perf_event_paranoid:

    Controls use of the performance events system by unprivileged users (without CAP_SYS_ADMIN). The default value is 2.

    -1: Allow use of (almost) all events by all users Ignore mlock limit after perf_event_mlock_kb without CAP_IPC_LOCK

    >=0: Disallow ftrace function tracepoint by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN Disallow raw tracepoint access by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN

    >=1: Disallow CPU event access by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN

    >=2: Disallow kernel profiling by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
```

from the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt)